# Iterar sobre componentes Swing recursivamente é estranho

Tags: java, swing, recursão

Para adicionar Listeners à todos os componentes do meu Frame eu estou Iterando sobre ele recursivamente:

```
private void adicionarListeners(Component componente)
    {
        Stack<Component> stack = new Stack<Component>();

        // evita adicionar o listener mais de uma vez no mesmo componente
        if (!componentesRegistrados.contains(componente)) {
            componente.addMouseListener(listenerMouse);
//            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Adicionou listener em {0}", componente.getName());
            System.out.println("Adicionou listner em "+componente.getName());
            componentesRegistrados.add(componente);
        }

        if (componente instanceof Container) {

            Container container = (Container) componente;
            int filhos = container.getComponentCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < filhos; i++) {
                adicionarListeners(container.getComponent(i));
            }

            container.addContainerListener(new ContainerAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e)
                {
                    adicionarListeners(e.getComponent());
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Estou tendo problema de estouro de pilha

Comment: Por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar e executar o código e assim simular o problema.

Comment: Então, não há um exemplo mínimo, o Overflow só acontece porque tem muita coisa (muitos componentes), mas a real questão é: como percorrer componentes do Swing (ou qualquer árvore) de maneira não recursiva

Comment: Sem um **[mcve]** fica dificil ajudar, porque não tem como saber que tipos de componentes tem na sua tela que possam conflitar esse metodo. De repente o problema dele é algo bobo que pode ser resolvido facilmente. Mas você precisa colaborar e fornecer um **[mcve]** para isso.

Comment: E é raro perguntas envolvendo swing serem respondidas sem um exemplo executável, ainda mais com esse nivel de complexidade. Sugiro que tente criar um código dentro dos moldes do link que postei, assim facilitará você obter resposta.

Comment: Não poderia ser hipoteticamente um caso em que não é uma árvore mas um grafo reincidente? Estourar stack com uma profundidade menor do que 50 de profundidade creio que não há

Comment: Vou ver se consigo reproduzir em outro exemplo @Articuno; btw Jefferson, estou colocando cada componente que cadastro em um HashMap "componentesRegistrados", logo a reincidencia Não deveria acontecer :(

Comment: Outro problema nesse código é que se o objetivo é adicionar listener em todos os componentes filhos, não deveria haver necessidade de chamar o próprio método dentro do listener de novo. O que deveria ser feito é checar se o componente corrente dentro do laço é do tipo Container, se for, vc chama o próprio método de forma recursiva, se não for, aplica o listener

Comment: Você tem 25 mil componentes na sua tela? Então o problema não é só do Java, mas também na estrutura da sua aplicação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEscobri :s

```
e.getComponent()
```

retorna o container em que vai ser adicionado, e não o componente que será adicionado: mudei para

```
e.getChild()
```

E agora funciona :o

Btw, Tenho muitos componentes na tela mesmo :s

Comment: Exatamente o que eu havia comentado.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/283563/iterar-sobre-árvores-não-recursivamente#comment578820_283563

Comment: yep, tinha entendido errado seu comment :s